# Magento 2.1.9 Mailchimp Abandoned cart not working

Tags: magento-2.1.9, mailchimp, abandoned-cart

I have tried following steps to setup Abandoned cart using Mailchimp module.

**Setup**

> - Magento 2.1.9
>
>   - Default abandoned cart automation (series of 3 emails) in MailChimp
>   - Sync with MailChimp listed as complete - I can see recent customers listed on MailChimp and ecommerce data for recent orders, Total
>       Products, Total Carts.
>   - Checked the table **cron_schedule** for the **job_code** **ebizmarts_ecommerce** and not found any error message
>   - Checked the table quote and confirmed that the quote was not converted.
>   - Checked the **tablemailchimp_sync_ecommerce** with **type = QUO** and related_id, and not found anything on mailchimp_sync_error table for
>       this quote

**Steps**

> - As a logged in user or guest, add items to cart and get to payment    step of checkout so that email address is captured in quote.
> - Ensure that eCommerce CRON job is running
> - Wait for whole day and maybe longer

**Expected Result**

> - An abandoned cart email and listing at least 1 email sent in    MailChimp

**Actual Result**

> - No email sent MailChimp lists
> - 0 emails sent out

Comment: Found soution for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mailchimp Abandoned cart working fine after syncing completed.

Comment: My account is sync still I am not getting :(  any idea ?

Comment: But images are broken in the email, since I've set pub as the root directory

Comment: How to check it is sync or not ?